# Tkinter GUI hangs when running while loop with Schedule

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, schedule

I have a button on my GUI that starts a process which has a while loop, because its a Schedule which works based on time. However, once the button is clicked the GUI hangs, but the actual program still is working in the background.

```
def start(root, period=0):
    schedule.every(float(delay)).hours.do(start)

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        root.after(30000, print("WAITING 30 SECONDS..."))
```

I want to be able to keep using the menu while the loop goes on in the background.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using an infinite loop like that. Instead, use `after` to call `run_pending` on a schedule.

For example, if you want to poll for pending events every thirty seconds, it might look something like this:

```
def start(root, period=0):
    schedule.every(float(delay)).hours.do(start))
    poll_schedule(schedule)

def poll_schedule(root, schedule)
    schedule.run_pending()
    print("WAITING 30 SECONDS...")
    root.after(30000, poll_schedule, root, schedule)
```